# Apache: pb with the Include directive => bash: Include: command not found

Tags: apache, include, debian

I'm setting up my Apache Web server (apache2) on my server running Debian 7.
However, using the "Include" directive to Include a conf file for Apache prompt me:

$Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

"bash: Include: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, instead of typing this line:

```
$Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

in my Terminal, I was supposed to add the line in the configuration file of Apache which is there for me: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

That makes much more sense as the "include" directive aims at keep the main apache.conf file as easy to read and maintain as possible by just including the paths to the "decentralized configuration files" that stay within the added modules. Like the "include" statement in C language for example.

If you don't understand what I mean, just have a look to: /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf